# Android - is it possible to open a database file that download from web services using "sqlite asset helper"?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, download, zip

This is the logic I am trying to achieve:

1. Download the database from web services
2. unzip it
3. load the database using SQLite asset helper
4. delete the zip file

I am wondering if it is possible to achieve using SQLite asset helper, or I should use other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQLiteAssetHelp` is designed to copy the database file from the assets folder, which is part of the shipped app package.

You already have the file; copying is not necessary.
Just open your file through `SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: Thank, very clear.

Just a wondering If you can help me out here
where should I store downloaded database so I can use SQLiteDatabase to open it.

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if it is possible to achieve using SQLite asset helper

No, sorry.